# Replace special characters?

Tags: powershell, replace, special-characters

I want to replace ",<*" with "*<" at the beginning of the line and the end "*>" with ">*". The below command is not working. Please assist.

```
$inputmatch = ",<*abc*>,<*>,<*abc*>,<*abc*>"     
$inputmatch = $inputmatch -replace "^\,\<\*","\*\<"   
$inputmatch = $inputmatch -replace "\*\>$","\>\*"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$inputmatch = ",<*abc*>,<*>,<*abc*>,<*abc*>"    
$inputmatch -replace '^,<\*','*<' -replace '\*>$','>*'

*<abc*>,<*>,<*abc*>,<*abc>*
```